# Error:Undeclared identifier 'TMyClass'

Tags: delphi

I'm practicing with code in embarcadero DataSnap.
When implementing the following code I get error message:
Error:Undeclared identifier 'TMyClass' on line 42
I'm fairly certain the error exist around:
 **PersistentClass := TMyClass;**

Any help is appreciated.

```
 unit MyServer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IPPeerServer, Datasnap.DSCommonServer,
  Datasnap.DSTCPServerTransport, Datasnap.DSServer;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DSServer1: TDSServer;
    DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass;
    DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport;
    procedure DSServerClass1GetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
      var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
    procedure DSServerClass1CreateInstance(
      DSCreateInstanceEventObject: TDSCreateInstanceEventObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.DSServerClass1CreateInstance(
  DSCreateInstanceEventObject: TDSCreateInstanceEventObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.DSServerClass1GetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
  var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin

      PersistentClass := TMyClass;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Well, and does the `TMyClass` class exist somewhere in the scope of this unit ? You cannot assign to that parameter something that doesn't exist.

Comment: It's helpful when following a tutorial to pay attention to all of the instructions.  See Step 3, point 3 : `For Delphi, add the name of this unit, MyClass, to the uses clause of the server application's unit MyServer.pas.`  -- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Tutorial:_Using_a_DataSnap_Server_with_an_Application

Comment: See also : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Programs_and_Units#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear. At the point where you use `TMyClass`, the compiler is unable to see a symbol with that name.

Most likey you have not declared it, or have omitted from the uses clause the unit in which it is declared.